# How to Skew Only One Side of a Button in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a web project where I have a specific design requirement for a button. The button needs to have a skewed effect, but only on one side. Specifically, I want the left side of the `Settings` button to be skewed, while the right side remains straight at 90 degrees.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Taskboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styling/home.css">
    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #333;
            color: white;
            
        }
        
        header {
            background-color: #222;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            padding-left: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        nav {
            position: relative; /* Ensure nav is positioned for absolute positioning of children */
            padding-left: 0;
        }
        
        nav h1 {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            background: #007bff; /* Set the background color to blue */
            position: relative; /* Ensure relative positioning for the nav h1 */
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            transform: skewX(-20deg);
            margin-left: -40px;
            padding-left: 50px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }



        




        
        nav .hamburger {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            color: white; /* Change the color of the hamburger icon to white for better visibility */
            padding-left: 150px;
        }
        
        .menu {
            list-style: none;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            left: 100%; /* Position to the right of the nav h1 */
            transform: scaleX(0); /* Initially collapsed along the X axis */
            transform-origin: left;
            transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out; /* Animate the transform property */
            background-color: #222;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); /* Optional: Add a shadow for better visibility */
        }
        
        .showNavMenu {
            transform: scaleX(1); /* Expand to full width */
        }
        
        ul li {
            display: block; /* Change to block for vertical list */
            padding: 5px;
          
            
        }
        
        .button-blue {
            background: #007bff; /* Assuming a solid blue; replace with gradient if needed */
            color: white;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-left: -15px; /* Space between buttons */
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition for hover effect */
            text-transform: uppercase; /* If the text should be uppercase as in the screenshot */
            transform: skewX(-20deg);
        }

        nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between; /* Adjust this to align the nav items as in the screenshot */
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px; /* Adjust as needed */
        }
        
        /* Style for the hamburger icon */
        nav .hamburger {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: white; /* Change the color of the hamburger icon to white for better visibility */
        }
        
        /* You might also want to style the <ul> element to have padding and margin 0 */
        nav ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex; /* To align the buttons horizontally */
        }
        
        /* Style for the <li> elements to remove list styles and margins */
        nav ul li {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
        }

        ul li button.button-blue:hover {
            background-color: blue; /* Keep the background color blue on hover */
        }


        .button-blue:hover {
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #0056b3, #004291);
            box-shadow: 0 2px #002b5e;
            transform: translateY(2px) skewX(-20deg); /* Add skew transformation here as well */
        }

        #new-taskboard-form {
            display: none;
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 8px;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form input[type="text"],
        #new-taskboard-form input[type="file"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form button {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form button:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form input[type="text"]::placeholder {
            color: #888;
        }

        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
        
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: 5% auto; /* 5% from the top and centered */
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
            border-radius: 8px; /* Optional: Rounded corners */
        }
        
        .close-button {
            color: #aaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        .close-button:hover,
        .close-button:focus {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .taskboard-selector {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #222;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between; /* Aligns items on opposite ends */
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <h1>My New Taskboard <span class="hamburger">&#9776;</span></h1>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><button id="update-button" class="button-blue">Update</button></li>
                <li><button id="edit-button" class="button-blue">Edit</button></li>
                <li><button id="open-button" class="button-blue">Open</button></li>
                <li><button id="new-button" class="button-blue">New</button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <button id="settings-button" class="button-blue">Settings</button> <!-- Moved outside of the nav, into the header -->
    </header>
    <main>

        <section class="taskboard-grid" id="taskboard-grid">
            <!-- Task cards will be dynamically added here -->
        </section>

        <!-- Hidden form for creating a new taskboard -->
        <div id="new-taskboard-form">
            <input type="text" id="new-taskboard-name" placeholder="Enter Taskboard Name">
            <input type="file" id="new-taskboard-file" accept=".xlsx">
            <button id="submit-new-taskboard">Create Taskboard</button>
        </div>        
    </main>

    <div id="taskboard-selection-modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
            <h2>Select a Taskboard</h2>
            <select id="taskboard-selector" class="taskboard-selector">
                <!-- Taskboard options will be dynamically populated here -->
            </select>
            <button id="select-taskboard-button" class="button-blue">Open Taskboard</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Toggle menu visibility
        const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
        const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
        hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
            menu.classList.toggle('showNavMenu');
        });
    
        // Open settings page
        document.getElementById('settings-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.location.href = 'settings';
        });
    
        // Global variable to keep track of the currently selected taskboard
        let currentTaskboard = null;
    
        // Update taskboard functionality
        document.getElementById('update-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!currentTaskboard) {
                alert('Please select a taskboard first.');
                return;
            }
    
            var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
            fileInput.type = 'file';
            fileInput.accept = '.xlsx';
    
            fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                var file = event.target.files[0];
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', file);
                formData.append('name', currentTaskboard);
    
                fetch('/upload/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    fetchTaskboardData(currentTaskboard);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
            });
    
            fileInput.click();
        });
    
        // Open taskboard selection modal
        document.getElementById('open-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            fetch('/list/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(taskboards => {
                populateTaskboardSelector(Object.values(taskboards));
                showModal();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching taskboards:', error);
            });
        });
    
        // Populate taskboard selector in modal
        function populateTaskboardSelector(taskboards) {
            var selector = document.getElementById('taskboard-selector');
            selector.innerHTML = '';
            taskboards.forEach(taskboard => {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = taskboard;
                option.textContent = taskboard;
                selector.appendChild(option);
            });
        }
    
        // Show modal
        function showModal() {
            var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
            modal.style.display = 'block';
        }
    
        // Close modal functionality
        document.querySelector('.close-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        });
    
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    
        // Handle taskboard selection from modal
        document.getElementById('select-taskboard-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var selectedTaskboard = document.getElementById('taskboard-selector').value;
            if (selectedTaskboard) {
                openTaskboard(selectedTaskboard);
                var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
                modal.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                alert('Please select a taskboard.');
            }
        });
    
        // Edit taskboard functionality
        document.getElementById('edit-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!currentTaskboard) {
                alert('Please select a taskboard first.');
                return;
            }
            window.location.href = `/edit?name=${encodeURIComponent(currentTaskboard)}`;
        });
    
        // New taskboard functionality
        document.getElementById('new-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('new-taskboard-form').style.display = 'block';
        });
    
        // Submit new taskboard
        document.getElementById('submit-new-taskboard').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var taskboardName = document.getElementById('new-taskboard-name').value;
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('new-taskboard-file');
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
    
            if (!taskboardName || !file) {
                alert('Please enter a taskboard name and select a file.');
                return;
            }
    
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', taskboardName);
            formData.append('file', file);
    
            fetch('/create', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Taskboard created:', data);
                document.getElementById('new-taskboard-form').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('new-taskboard-name').value = '';
                fileInput.value = '';
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        });
    
        // Function to fetch and display taskboard data
        function fetchTaskboardData(taskboardName) {
            console.log('Fetching data for:', taskboardName); // Debug log
            fetch(`/get/?name=${encodeURIComponent(taskboardName)}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Data received:', data); // Debug log
                var taskboardGrid = document.getElementById('taskboard-grid');
                taskboardGrid.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content
        
                // Check if data is an object and not an array
                if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null && !Array.isArray(data)) {
                    Object.values(data).forEach(createCard); // Iterate over object values
                } else {
                    console.error('Unexpected data format:', data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching taskboard data:', error);
            });
        }
    
        // Function to create a card for each task
        function createCard(row) {
            console.log('Creating card for:', row); // Debug log
            var card = document.createElement('div');
            card.className = 'task-card';
    
            Object.keys(row).forEach(key => {
                if (row[key] !== null && row[key] !== undefined) {
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.textContent = `${key}: ${row[key]}`;
                    card.appendChild(p);
                }
            });
    
            document.getElementById('taskboard-grid').appendChild(card); // Append card to taskboard grid
        }
    
        // Open taskboard function
        function openTaskboard(taskboardName) {
            currentTaskboard = taskboardName;
            fetchTaskboardData(taskboardName);
        }
    
        // DOMContentLoaded event listener
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const taskboardName = urlParams.get('name');
            if (taskboardName) {
                openTaskboard(taskboardName);
            }
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how it looks right now:

[image]

Here is how it should look:

[image]

I attempted to apply a skew transformation to the button, but this skews the entire button. I'm unsure how to apply the skew effect to just one side of the button.

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this effect using CSS? Are there any tricks or techniques involving pseudo-elements or other CSS properties that could create this skewed effect on only one side of a button?